# Cannot read JavaScript errors in Firebug console before page reloads

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebug

I'm debugging some JavaScript and I have a submit button that should run a jquery function to run a script via Ajax. When I click the button, an error is displayed in the Firebug console but I don't have time to read it before the form is submitted and thus the page is reloaded.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In version 1.8.3 (at least) you can click the "Persist" button to keep console information around after reload.

Answer (score 9):

Use the Persist button to not clear the console

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to simply use `alert(err);`.

Sometimes alerts just works better.

Answer (score 0):

Go to browser console settings --> Check "Preserve Log"